# Is it possible to remove title underneath iOS home screen widget?

Tags: ios, swift, title, home-screen-widget

Many users ask me, can you remove title underneath the widget?

But as per Apple's design guidelines, we can't keep the app name empty or remove the home screen widget title.

Does anyone already fixed this issue?

[image]

Comment: Your cannot remove the name. Perhaps your name could be improved so that it feels more natural there? Do you mind sharing the name and the widget purpose?

Comment: Hey, @LouFranco thanks. Yes, we can improve name by a short string. But lots of users want a completely blank title. Because It's clock widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set a name and it must be at least three characters. Maybe try clock emojis like .

See this app for another idea: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dash-dot-dash/id1533706044

They named the app -.-

Comment: this hack worked before but now Apple rejects app updates if the app name is something non-readable. They changed their guidemlines.